# Vue/Buefy - Hide dropdown on router-link click / SPA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bulma, buefy

I am having some issues using [**Buefy**](https://buefy.github.io/#/documentation/dropdown) and Vue. I have a simple SPA (Single Page Application), that uses `vue-router`. I have a dropdown that looks like this:

```
  <b-dropdown class="user-dropdown" v-model="navigation" position="is-bottom-left">
    <a class="navbar-item" slot="trigger">
      <span class="tag is-rounded has-text-weight-semibold avatar">OB</span>
    </a>
    <div class="columns is-marginless">
      <div class="column has-text-centered">
        <router-link to="home">
          <b-icon class="is-large is-size-4" icon="ion-ionic ion-ios-search"></b-icon>
        </router-link>
      </div>
      <div class="column has-text-centered">
        <router-link to="dashboard">
          <b-icon class="is-large is-size-4" icon="ion-ionic ion-ios-contact"></b-icon>
        </router-link>
      </div>

    </div>
  </b-dropdown>
```

Getting the dropdown to show works fine. It also hides if I click anywhere on the page, outside of the visible dropdown.

My problem is, that I have a single page application, so when I "change" page (click a link), the dropdown is still visible when the page changes.

**Example:**

On below page:

```
www.example.com/#/home
```

I click on the dropdown, which opens, and then click on the `dashboard` link, which gives me:

```
www.example.com/#/dashboard
```

But the dropdown is still visible.

Anyone know how I can do, so the dropdown will toggle when I click on the links inside it?

**Update:**
I use the Vue Dev tools in Chrome, and I can see that when I click on the dropdown so it toggles to active, I see this:

```
name:"active-change"
type:"$emit"
source:"<BDropdown>"
payload:Array[1]
0:true
```

And when I click anywhere on the page, to close the dropdown, it looks like this:

```
name:"active-change"
type:"$emit"
source:"<BDropdown>"
payload:Array[1]
0:false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the drop-down is watching for state isn't changing, because in a SPA it's just javascript. I don't know about the specifics regarding Buefy, but you'll have to set the state variable on router load, or watch some kind of variable to tell the menu that something in another part of your app is different.

Comment: Just updated my original question to include the events, if that can be of any help. I am still new to Vue - so just trying to learn the basics.

Comment: It looks like it's emitting a custom event from the component. This means that the parent, where the component is called, should have a method that the bubbled event calls. [Vue docs regarding custom events behavior](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

Comment: If I use `@click.native` I can fire a function, which I define in my `methods()`. However I can’t figure out how to hide the dropdown when I click on a `<router-link> / <a>` inside the dropdown.

Comment: Could you paste in some of the component you're talking about?